# Primefaces full page layout header alignment and size

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces full page layout and I want to change header's alignment and header's font size. When i add

```
style="border: none;alignment-adjust: middle;font-size: larger"
```

to the Primefaces LayoutUnit, it just removes the border and doesn't do anything about alignment and font size. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  the "!important" flag after each style that is not used.

maybe primefaces overrides the styles.

to force your styles to be used try the following code:

```
style="border: none;alignment-adjust: middle !important;font-size: larger !important;"
```